# content-type in jquery $.ajaxSetup() call not getting applied

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

           $(document).ready(function () {

                $.ajaxSetup({ 
        type: 'POST',
            url: 'AjaxService.asmx/GetBorughs',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=uft-8',
            dataType:'json'
        });
        $('#btnCount').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                success: function (respo) {
                    $("#log").html('').append("<ul id='boroughList'>");
                    var places = respo.d;
                    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
                        $("#boroughList").append('<li>' + places[i].Name + ' ' + places[i].population + ' ' + places[i].created + '</li>');
                    }
                    $("#log").append('</ul>');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please see below my web service method that is getting called, from the above ajax call:

```
 public class Borough
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int population { get; set; }
            public short created { get; set; }
        }

        List<Borough> boroughs = new List<Borough>
        {
            new Borough{Name="Andhra",population=10000,created=1940},
            new Borough{Name="TN",population=20000,created=1945},
            new Borough{Name="Kerala",population=30000,created=1950},
            new Borough{Name="Karnataka",population=40000,created=1955}
        };


        [WebMethod]
        public List<Borough> GetBorughs()
        {
            return boroughs;
        }
```

Question : I am calling a webService method from jquery ajax. If the $.ajax() call has content-Type anddataType  set to  json, i am getting response as json object. But if I set the same content-Type & dataType set to  json in $.ajaxSetup() call, I am getting xml response. If i keep the same options in the $.Ajax() call, then i am getting json object. Please tell me why ajaxSetup call is not able to set the return type.

Comment: is there any other ajaxSetup call in the page which might be resetting the value of contentType

Comment: No Arun there is only one ajaxSetup .

Comment: can you check the request headers using the network tab of browser developer tools

Comment: try also to set the `accepts` header also like `accepts: 'application/json'` - what is the jQuery version used

Comment: I am using jquery-1.10.2.

Comment: check the value of `Accept` header that is sent to the server in both the cases

Comment: Accept header is application/json,text/javascript,*/*;q=0.01

Comment: what is the value of accept

Comment: In both the cases Accept header is same:

Comment: application/json,text/javascript,*/*;q=0.01

Answer (score 0):

As documented in official site its recommended not to use `jQuery.ajaxSetup()` Api .

As documented in jQuery website :-

> **Description**: Set default values for future Ajax requests. Its use is
> not recommended.
>
> The settings specified here will affect all calls to $.ajax or
> Ajax-based derivatives such as $.get(). This can cause undesirable
> behavior since other callers (for example, plugins) may be expecting
> the normal default settings. **For that reason we strongly recommend
> against using this API.** Instead, set the options explicitly in the
> call or define a simple plugin to do so.

Comment: Yes Neel, it is not recommended. But i want to know why this is behaving differently in the two cases i mentioned above.